# Image pattern to SVG path showing stretched

Tags: svg, background-image

I have a rectangular div, where I added a `background-color`, and `background-image` with repeat on, so that the semi-transparent image blend with the background color and make a colorful patterned background for my content. I took a pattern from [SubtlePatterns](https://www.toptal.com/designers/subtlepatterns/) which is: `300px × 295px` in dimension. Here's the code:

```
#nd {
    background-image: url('../images/dark-mosaic.png');
    background-color: #b33939;
    color: #fff;
}
```

Now I wanted to make the harsh rectangle a bit smoother, so I took an SVG separator from [this link](https://tympanus.net/Development/SectionSeparators/). Used [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11500364/1743124) to make an SVG path background image. With the following code:

```
<svg id="curveUpColor" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="100%" height="100" viewBox="0 0 100 100" preserveAspectRatio="none">
    <defs>
        <pattern id="img1" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" width="300" height="295">
            <image xlink:href="{{ asset('images/dark-mosaic.png') }}" x="0" y="0" width="300" height="295" />
        </pattern>
    </defs>
    <path d="M0 100 C 20 0 50 0 100 100 Z" fill="url(#img1)"></path>
</svg>
```

I ended up with a SVG shape with stretched/filled background image:

[image: Dark Mosaic Pattern to the SVG]

I consulted [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47183986/1743124) and fixed the width and height attribute of the `<image>` tag to the width and height of the image file, but I failed.

Now I have two questions:

- How can I make the background image to be tiled exactly like the rectangle?
- How can I put a fill color to the shape so that the SVG pattern matched with the pattern in the rectangle?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a `section` element and an `svg` element and try to match the pattern for both elements you can use only the `section` and a `clipPath` to clip the `section` as you need.

The path for the "pattern" I'm using has fill="black". The `section` has `background-color: skyBlue;`

Please observe that the clipPath is using `clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox"` and the `d` attribute has values from 0 to 1.

```css
#nd {
  height:300px;
  background-color:skyBlue;
  background-image: url("data:image/svg+xml,%3Csvg viewBox='0 0 40 40' width='40' height='40' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'%3E%3Cg fill='black'%3E%3Crect x='0' y='0' width='20' height='20'/%3E%3Crect x='20' y='20' width='20' height='20'/%3E%3C/g%3E%3C/svg%3E");
   -webkit-clip-path: url(#clip);
  clip-path: url(#clip);  
}
```

```html
<svg height="0" width="0" class="svg-clip" style="position:absolute">
    <defs>
         <clipPath id="clip" clipPathUnits="objectBoundingBox">  
            <path d="M0 .5 C .20 0 .50 0 1 .5 v.5H0Z"></path>
        </clipPath>
      </defs>
</svg>
<section id="nd"></section>
```

For the `background-image` I'm using a data:Uri image but you can use the external image.

If you take a look at the svg used as an image you'll see this (not a pattern!). Since css is by default repeating the image you don't need a pattern, just an image that is repeating.

```html
<svg viewBox='0 0 40 40' width='40' height='40' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2000/svg' xmlns:xlink='http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink'>
    <g fill="black">
        <rect x='0' y='0' width='20' height='20'/>
        <rect x='20' y='20' width='20' height='20'/>
    </g>
</svg>
```

I hope you'll find this helpful.

Comment: Thank you. This obviously is a correct answer, but I'm struggling with several things. First of all, I never used `<clipPath>`, so I can't modify your solution for a rotated-mirror image for both sides of the `<section>`.  The pattern I tried to encode into base64 using [this site](https://www.base64-image.de/) produced huge amount of code and that's a `data:image/png...` not like yours `data:image/svg+xml`. I'm not using a SVG pattern, mine is `.png` file. Though I skipped the `height` and went with `padding`. And I'm also concerned with the browser support.